# Can't store libcurl results. (Outputs empty files or doesn't write in memory)

Tags: c, libcurl

I'm trying to build a connect4 that could beat you at the game and since I'm no expert in AI I decided to get the moves the computer does from a website (I get a JSON files).
I've tried many solutions but libcurl seamed to work best. I managed to get a correct output in prompt.

It's weird because I get a display when I don't want to put it in memory and as soon as I try to save it anywere it disapears. I've tried different website only the one I want is affected.

Here's the JSON want http://connect4.gamesolver.org/solve?pos=44

But when I tried to put either the string into memory or in a file it just writes nothing. (I've used the code provided by libcurl...

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/url2file.html I just get an empty file

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html I says 0 bytes written ).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>

static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
  return written;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURL *curl_handle;
  static const char *pagefilename = "page.out";
  FILE *pagefile;

  if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <URL>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* init the curl session */ 
  curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

  /* set URL to get here */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, argv[1]);

  /* Switch on full protocol/debug output while testing */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

  /* disable progress meter, set to 0L to enable and disable debug output */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);

  /* send all data to this function  */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

  /* open the file */ 
  pagefile = fopen(pagefilename, "wb");
  if(pagefile) {

    /* write the page body to this file handle */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pagefile);

    /* get it! */ 
    curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

    /* close the header file */ 
    fclose(pagefile);
  }

  /* cleanup curl stuff */ 
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

  curl_global_cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not set `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, the function that libcurl should call back to for actually writing your data, and `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`, the stream that should be passed to that function. Look again at your [first tutorial](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/url2file.html):

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
  return written;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ...
    /* send all data to this function  */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

    /* open the file */ 
    pagefile = fopen(pagefilename, "wb");
    if(pagefile) {

      /* write the page body to this file handle */ 
      curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pagefile);

      /* get it! */ 
      curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

      /* close the header file */ 
      fclose(pagefile);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The result is that your request is actually sent, the reply received, but the data isn't written anywhere.

**Update:**

The code from your updated post works fine for me. I therefore assume your problem lies elsewhere. Try this instead of the original filehandling part:

```
  char errorbuf[ CURL_ERROR_SIZE ] = "";
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorbuf); 

  /* open the file */ 
  pagefile = fopen(pagefilename, "wb");
  if(pagefile) {

    /* write the page body to this file handle */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pagefile);

    /* get it! */ 
    if ( curl_easy_perform(curl_handle) != CURLE_OK )
    {
      fputs( errorbuf, stderr );
    }

    /* close the header file */ 
    fclose(pagefile);
  }
  else
  {
    perror( "fopen failed" );
  }
```

Note that, while tutorials usually skip proper error handling, what I showcased above *should* be part of "real" code anyway.

Comment: Also, duplicate.

Comment: I sorry my post wasn't clear, I know the code I posted isn't suppose to write anything in memory. It's when I use the code from the  tutorial that it doesn't write anything (and there isn't any errors).

Comment: @ArthurMilon: Then please post the *exact* code that isn't working for you, because the *exact* code from the tutorials is working just fine, and we cannot find errors you aren't showing us. ;-) That's what a [mcve] is for (and why it is more or less required by SO).

Comment: I've updated the post

Comment: @ArthurMilon: See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works !!!! After some testing of my old code it was only malfunctionning with connect4.gamesolver.org  (google and some others worked just fine). But you seem to have resolved my problem. I'll try a similar solution to store in memory instead. 
Thank you again